# Should one report a mistake if he or she is not working on the project?

Tags: team

What would you suggest if one works in a company but finds something wrong on some part of the company he or she is not working on? Let's say for example that a secretary or even his or her friend finds a misprint or SQL-injection on company's website. Is it help or hinder if he or she concentrates on wrong subjects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you find a mistake regardless of who's mistake it is and there is potential to impact company operations or systems (IT, financial etc), then you should report it. The last thing you want is to see something and do nothing about it; especially if it can generate blow back later on. Reporting it is a matter of supporting the company and the best interest of all stakeholders. Report the matter to the appropriate chain of command and let them decide how to best respond.

Comment: You need to be VERY CARFUL here. Talk to the wrong person, and things can go wrong. You need to figure out who to actually tell; somebody who will action it properly and not kick up a fuss, create an internal security panic, or accuse you of "hacking".

Sometimes, what would usually be the appropriate chain of command isn't appropriate for security holes because people react badly when they hear of a serious issue that isn't part of their normal job to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put all mistakes in the same bucket.  A "your" when it should be "you're" does not warrent reporting unless it is in a contract.  A SQL injection vulnerability on an outward facing server then yes report it.  If in doubt ask you're boss.

Comment: You don't think a grammatical error on the company website is worth pointing out?

Comment: @Carson63000 The question is should (not worth).  If you want to report it fine but if I have work to do I am going to do my work.

Comment: Interesting. Not an attitude I'd ever want to see in any of my reports, but to each their own.

Comment: @Carson63000 If they did not finish their assigned tasks and at the end of the day told you they were busy with a series of non critical tasks related to other departments you would reward them?

Comment: `Ask you're boss` - I see what you did there. Well played. :)

Comment: If you can't finish your assigned tasks because it takes you a significant amount of time to fire off an email about a typo on the website, that's a whole separate problem. But yes, I'd rather someone who cares about the business than someone who just wants to sit in a box and work on "his" work.

Comment: @Carson63000 I don't follow your logic.  Someone that sits in a box and does assigned work does not care about the business?

Comment: @Blam - precisely. They only care about doing "their" thing, with no interest or enthusiasm to look at how they can contribute to the bigger picture. Don't get me wrong, there are plenty of jobs that just require grunt work. But I got the impression that you were a developer, and that's not one of those jobs.

Comment: @Carson63000 Cool and I am a developer.  I do feel I contribute to bigger picture by doing my job (with interest and enthusiasm).  I do high end boring grunt server side stuff.